# Multi Dimensional Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to extend my already existing Taxonomy list by a second value per existing one. Let's say I have a Taxonomy list like this:

- First Item
- Second Item
- Third Item

Now i want to store a second value (FI, SI, TI) to receive a list:

- First Item | FI
- Second Item | SI
- Third Item | TI

where I can access either the first or the second value of one taxonomy item. Is that somehow possible?

The only thing I would know to achieve that, is a custom content type.

Comment: Do you want to have two independent taxonomies per node, so each value from first can be paired with any value from second dictionary? Or do you want to create an independent "subtree" / "sublist" for each of existing terms, like  red, green, blue for "colour" and sweet, sour, salty for "taste"?

Comment: I do want two lists where one value is paired with one specific value from a second list. Or one list where every value consists of two values.

Comment: So all you want is, basically, to rename taxonomy values to give them appearance of twofold names? If there is, logically, one value (because pairing is constant), why renaming is not enough?

Comment: No, I don't want to rename them. I want two values which I can access individually. But they should be paired.

Comment: What do you mean "access individually" if you want them to be always set and displayed together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new field to taxonomy terms. Go to vocabulary and than to Manage Fileds tabs and add new textfiled. After that you can edit you tems and add seecond values.

Comment: omg, how could I've not seen that o_O

Comment: in Drupal 7 node, comments, taxonomy terms, user profiles are entity and have fields ability. https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744